# What is the namespace for the math functions in XPath and XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

XPath defines  [some mathematical functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-xpath-functions-30-20140408/#trigonometry). These functions come with the prefix math:. I wonder what is the namespace for 'math'. It turns out that I can't execute the following XSLT in XMLSpy:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="pi()"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined [in the same document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-xpath-functions-30-20140408/#namespace-prefixes) as `http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math`